# Keyboard Shortcut in Python-Jupyter is not working

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

In Jupyter-Notebook one can find under Help - Keyboard Shortcuts the command Indent: **Ctrl - ]** .

For some reason this command does not work and i need to do it manually. Every time i press **Crtl + Alt + 9** nothing happens.

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: there is no shortcut key with Ctrl+ Shift + 9. **Ctrl+]** is working fine in Chrome and Internet Explorer.

Comment: I updated my post. To get the symbol ** ] ** you are using the combination alt + 9 right?

Comment: No.. you can edit the shortcuts in the keyboard shortcuts option in jupyter notebook. here my doubt is what you are trying with ** Ctrl + Alt + 9** ?

Comment: I am using a german keyboard and it does not have a single key with the symbol ** ] **. I can create ** ] **  by pressing Alt + 9 simultaneously. Therefore im trying to use  Crtl + Alt + 9 for the indent command but for some reason it does not work.